# unite function in tidyr package doesn't work

Tags: r, string, tidyr

I am trying to deal with some characters.

The code looks like this:

```
library(tidyr)
unite(data ,sep="%in% ")
```

Here `data` is a data frame, which looks like this:

```
   A      B
1  Var   'Y'
```

I can run it successfully under R 3.4.4.

```
1 Var%in% 'Y'
```

But in R 3.5.1, it will tell me the error:

```
Error in is_string(expr) : argument "expr" is missing, with no default
```

How to solve this problem?

Sorry for not specifying the problem before. I have now figured it out what the problem is.

Comment: You've got three lines with `toString` - which one?

Comment: I don't see this error when knitting in RStudio with R 3.5.1.

Comment: Does it only happen when knitting? Can you make it happen at the command line? Does it only happen when writing to a file? Is it the `cat`? What does the traceback look like?

Comment: @Spacedman It also happens when I run it at the command line.

Comment: Problem edited.

Comment: Please edit the title to reflect that this is *not* a problem with the version of R but is a problem with the version of the `tidyr` package. This works with v 0.8.1 but fails with 0.8.3 in R 3.4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a name for the new column, e.g.

```
unite(data, "newcol", sep = "%in%")
```

This would appear to work without 3 arguments if you use a pipe, e.g.

```
data %>% unite("newcol", sep = "%in%")
```

but the pipe operator is really just hiding the fact that `data` is the first argument.

Edited to add:  Your original form did work in `tidyr` version 0.8.1 (as pointed out by @Spacedman), but the dataframe it produced was invalid.  This bug was fixed sometime after that.